How can I ensure that macOS permissions for keyboard and mouse control persist across builds?
I’m writing C++ on macOS (Sequoia 15.0.1) and using XCode 16. I’m using the SFML (2.6.1) library and my programs need to use functions that control the mouse cursor or query the realtime state of the keyboard. MacOS is set up to require permissions being granted to the application to use those features. Setting the permissions in the Privacy & Security settings tab the first time is not a problem, but I understand that these permissions are supposed to persist across builds, and that is not what is happening.
Every time I make a one-character tweak to the source code and build/run afresh, the game doesn’t respond to the keyboard.
Is there a setting or configuration in XCode that will help the OS to recognize successive builds of this project as having mouse and keyboard permissions?
For the most part, this has only been an issue since I made a big switch from:

2017 Intel MacBook Air to 2023 ARM/M3 MacBook Pro
MacOS 10.14 Mojave to MacOS 15 Sequoia
XCode 10.1 to XCode 16
SFML 2.5.1 to 2.6.1

However, even in the old setup I had a permissions issue in the single instance of trying to move the cursor by fiat to a new location. But never any keyboard issues.
My XCode workspace projects were all created under the earlier setup. I’ve also set a custom working directory in the scheme of the project I'm currently trying to troubleshoot, because otherwise it doesn’t seem to be possible to use relative paths for loading resource files.

I don't see an option for me to "answer" my own question, so I'll post it here.

In Xcode menu choose Settings. In Settings choose Accounts tab. If you haven't added your Apple ID to the list, click the "+" and do so. You should now have a "team" that looks like `My Name (Personal Team). Then go to the "Signing and Capabilities" tab (which appears in the tab set along with "Build Settings" and "Build Phases" etc.) Now make sure that "Team" is set to "My Name (Personal Team)", make sure your bundle identifier is filled out uniquely, and make sure that "Signing Certificate" is set to "Developer", and not "Run Locally".

Somewhere in the process you should end up with a "MyProject.entitlements" file. With this settings combo I was able to stop the continual permissions lockouts after every code tweak.
